# constructing URL dynamically from incoming query parameter

Tags: xslt

I want to construct a URL dynamically and want to call that URL .

Below is the XSLT code snippet i am trying to do for creation of URL.

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="concat('https://google.com/root/rest/info/getData/?alt=xml&userName=',string($user), '&password=',string($password)"/>
```

The value of userName and password need to picked dynamically which i am getting in variable like $user and $password.

Can somebody help how i can create this URL dynamically using XSLT.

Comment: Does that not work for generating the URL...? The only problem I could think of is that you might need to URL encode the variables if they have weird characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ampersand as `&amp;` in XML:

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="concat('https://google.com/root/rest/info/getData/?alt=xml&amp;userName=', $user, '&amp;password=', $password)"/>
```

As for "calling", if the rest service returns XML then doing `<xsl:variable name="response" select="document($url)"/>` should do to retrieve the XML.